# create a quiz website /database extraction

Tags: javascript, database, facebook

I am trying to build a website of multiple choice quizzes. 
I have already seen some models out there like this one http://survley.com/start/what-kind-of-house-are-you.html

I have already created a small database but I can't have it like this one, fetching me the next question without changing the page.
could you tell me how this site is built? I mean, how is its database built and how does it function? do I need a Facebook app?
thank you

Comment: The url changes for every question in the example page you gave. Not sure what you want.

Comment: could you tell me how this website is built? how does it fetch the questions from database? i am all confused? does it use a facebook app? how is it built?

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to use is called AJAX. Basically it's using JavaScript to fetch what has to be shown for the next question from your server and send the provided answers to your server.
Using a library like [jQuery](http://jquery.com) one can update the pages content really simple.

Comment: could you please tell me how and where I should start doing this? give me some few tips please

Comment: for example this site apparently uses this facebook app appId=211665475703856
what is this app all about? how can I make one?

Comment: Would you please describe exactly what you want to achieve?

Comment: I want to build exactly the same site as i put it above
like this http://survley.com/start/what-kind-of-house-are-you.html
i want to build my own quizzes and answers. But how can I build exactly the same structure? where should I start from?

Comment: Start with the general layout of the site in html5 and css. Tweak it until it fits your idea. Then build an API on top of your database (so that you can simply access and update the data via http requests. If you're using php i recommend [slimframework]( http://www.slimframework.com) to help you keep it nice and clean. When the api is done include (jQuery)[http://jquery.com) in your html5 page and start writing js code to use your api via AJAX to update the site.